# Android: MultipartEntity addpart Double

Tags: java, android, multipartentity

Is there a way to send a Double value as part of an MultiPartEntity?

I have captured a user's location as latitude and longitude which are Double values. Am not sure how to send these through an `addpart`. Or is this something that needs to be handled in the server an not the client i.e. client sends it as a String and the String is converted to Double by the server?

Thanks.

Comment: yes you can do that sending location's latitude and longitude as String to server and then converting back string to double on server.

Comment: Thanks, I ended up doing that.